# Classification of maximally non-hamiltonian graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

A graph is called maximally non-hamiltonian, if it does
 not contain a hamilton-cycle, but no edge can be added without creating a 
 hamilton-cycle. In other words, every pair of non-adjacent vertices $(u/v)$
 can be connected with a hamiltonian path.

- How can the maximally non-hamiltonian graphs be classified with known graph properties ?

Comment: OEIS states that the number of maximally non-hamiltonian graphs with $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ vertices is $0,1,1,1,3,3,7,9,18,31$. Can someone enumerate these graphs and list those with maximum degree $<n-1$, if n is the number of vertices ?

Answer (score -1):

Using the edge count. If there is a non-Hamiltonian graph $G$ on $n$ vertices, the maximal number of edges that $G$ can contain is ${n-1\choose 2} +1 = {n\choose 2} - (n-2).$

Comment: This is confusing.  The maximum number of edges in a graph with $n$ vertices is $\binom{n}{2}$.   Perhaps you are trying to argue something about edges of a special kind of graph, like discussed in the Question.  But your one-line answer fails to make such a connection clear.

Comment: The question refers to non-Hamiltonian graphs. What I've written is true for such a graph. I will edit my response.

Comment: So are you saying that maximally non-hamiltonian graphs can be classified by counting the number of edges?  Does this tell us how many (up to isomorphism) maximally non-hamiltonian graphs on $5$ vertices there are?

Comment: There is a unique Extremal graph with the number of edges I listed on $n$ vertices so that there is no Hamilton cycle. Many graphs with fewer edges are not Hamiltonian, but they will not be maximally so.

Comment: If your claim that the extremal graph was unique were true, then counting edges would work to classify them (as would counting the vertices).  But the OP has referenced [OEIS sequence A185306](https://oeis.org/A185306), according to which there are three distinct maximally non-Hamiltonian graphs on $5$ vertices.